# How to get id of the selected row using jtable

Tags: jquery, jquery-jtable

How to get id of the selected row, i using `jtable`.
I sow event selectionchanged but i do not know how to get first cell of the selected row which is the id.
Name of the table is `tModelIndex`

```
selectionChanged: function () {
    var $selectedRows = $('#tModelIndex').jtable('selectedRows');
    if ($selectedRows.length > 0) {
        // alert(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: tModelIndex is a div sorry

Answer (score 4):

Check this [link](http://www.jtable.org/Demo/SelectingRows) here you can find simple example  

Make sure you have used this features in `jTable`

```
selecting: true, //Enable selecting
multiselect: true, //Allow multiple selecting
selectingCheckboxes: true  //Show checkboxes on first column
```

And then in *selectionChanged* event

```
selectionChanged: function () {
        //Get all selected rows
        var $selectedRows = $('#tModelIndex').jtable('selectedRows');
        if ($selectedRows.length > 0) {
            //Show selected rows
            $selectedRows.each(function () {
                var record = $(this).data('record');
                alert(record.StudentId);
                alert(record.Name);
            });
         } else {
             //No rows selected logic here
        }
    }
```

In this `record.StudentId`, **StudentId** means your column name in jTable